# Laravel displaying many to many relationship items

Tags: php, laravel

I have set up a many to many relationship in Laravel and have the database table populated with data.  The relationship setup looks like this...

```
users.php
---------
   public function houses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\House')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }

house.php
---------
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

In my /house/show.blade.php I am trying to display the saved connections like this...

```
$houses = House::with('App\User')->all();

foreach ($houses as $house) {
    echo 'Found House';
}
```

It is giving me an error saying that $houses can not be found.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: why in blade and not in controller ?

Comment: It should be  `House::with('users')`.

Comment: Am I better off doing this in the controller rather than the blade?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should indicate the relationship in the `with` method like this :

```
$houses = House::with('users')->get();
```

And one more thing it's better to get houses in the controller and pass them to the view :

```
$houses = House::with('users')->get();
return view('someView')->withHouses($houses);
```

And in the view do it like this :

```
@foreach ($houses as $house)
    {{ $house->addres }}
@endforeach
```

---

To get only the houses taht has the users try this :

```
$houses = House::has('users')->get();
```

And to add some conditions on the users you can do it like this :

```
$houses = House::whereHas('users', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'some user name'); // to add some conditions on the user :)
})->get();
```

Comment: I think it goes ->get(); at the end.

Comment: Whenever I try to set that in the controller I get - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()

Comment: @fightstarr20 Done now check it i used `get` not `all`

Comment: Now I get Call to undefined relationship [App\User] on model [App\House].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158859/discussion-between-maraboc-and-fightstarr20).

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
$houses = House::with('users')->get();

foreach ($houses as $house) {
    echo 'Found House';
}
```

**OR**

**In controller:**

```
use House;

$houses = House::with('users')->get();
return view('someView',compact('houses'));
```

**In Blade file:**

```
@foreach ($houses as $house)
    {{ $house->name }}
@endforeach
```